# How to change the decimal in which excel rounds (Default is .50, I need it to round up or down at .20 regarudless of the number preceding the decimal)

Tags: excel, function, rounding

For example, Anything between #.0 & #.02 will round down to #. Anything between #.2 & #.99 will round up to the nearest #.

I'm using the pound sign to indicate that the leading number should not have any effect on the result, but rather will be affected by the first decimal place.

8.1 should round to 8
8.21 should round to 9
17.1 should round to 17
17.8 should round to 18
etc.

I basically need to modify the standard .5 rounding rule to operate the same way but to use .2 as the cut off.

Hopefully I am not cutting the legs out from underneath me with this criteria, but I am looking for a formula/formatting solution only (non-VBA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a *bias* to your tested value to get the effect you want:

```
ROUND(value + 0.3, 2)
```

To round up earlier, and hold to two decimal places.  Adding a bias this way allows you to control rounding (up) and exploit the built-in behavior of the built-in formula.

Comment: This needs to be modified to ROUND(value + .03, 0) to round the nearest whole number.

Comment: What an elegant solution though. A little disappointed I didn't think of this on my own. Thank you very much.

Comment: Scott you have the reputation to accept my answer with the checkbox, might I trouble you to do that if you found this helpful?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Answer cred secured

Answer (score 0):

With a value in **C1**, in another cell enter:

```
=IF(C1-INT(C1)<=0.2,0,1)+INT(C1)
```

[image]